Issue with Google Geocoding API for Certain ZIP Codes
I am reaching out to report an issue I have encountered with the Google Geocoding API that has significantly impacted the functionality of my application. Specifically, the problem lies in the inability of the API to correctly process certain ZIP codes, which subsequently affects the retrieval of coordinates for task addresses within my application.
The issue manifests itself in the following manner: When attempting to geocode addresses using ZIP codes such as 95014, the API fails to return the expected results. This failure prevents my application from accurately determining the coordinates for these addresses, thereby hindering the ability to display nearby tasks based on location. Conversely, when using ZIP codes like 11201, the API functions as intended, successfully returning the coordinates and allowing for the proper display of nearby tasks.
This inconsistency in the API's performance across different ZIP codes poses a significant challenge for my application's users, particularly those located in areas with problematic ZIP codes. The inability to accurately determine the proximity of tasks based on location severely limits the utility of my application and negatively impacts the user experience.
I have taken steps to ensure that the addresses being passed to the API are correctly formatted and that the issue is not related to the input data.
Given the critical nature of this issue for my application's functionality and user experience, I kindly request your assistance in resolving this matter.Maybe it's because there are too many requests to the API? For example, if I have a list of more than 10 tasks, not a single zip code works.
I tried changing the number of tasks, it helps, but in my application there will be much more than 10 of them, and I don’t understand what problem I’m facing
